# Drawing image on canvas not working on FireFox

Tags: html, image, firefox, canvas

I'm working on drawing eyeDropper icon on a canvas where the user clicks. now it worked fine on **Google chrome**, but while testing it on **FireFox** it's not working as expected.

the code for drawing image:

```
function showPoint(){
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = '../dfe/svgs/target.svg';
    base_image.onload = function(){
        parent.targetISshown = true;
        context.drawImage(base_image, parent.currentMouseClickPosition.x - 10, parent.currentMouseClickPosition.y -10, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

now this is image viewed on **Google Chrome**:

[image]

and this is the image viewed on **FireFox**:

[image]

i tried to find out what is the problem with fireFox and images on canvas, i found that there is a different way to draw images on **FireFox**.

any helps?

Comment: You will need to show us your svg's markup as it sounds here lies the problem. Does the `<svg>` tag has a width and height set to absolute units?

Comment: its an image, how to get a svg tag?

Comment: `src="...target.svg"` this image is an svg image. Open it in a text editor and you will find svg markup (xml like). Make sure that the first `<svg>` tag has `width` and `height` attributes set and that they aren't set to relative units (like %). Then if you still face the issue, [edit] your question with the svg markup.

Comment: thanks alot :D, your comment is very helpful